# Разбить архив на тома с максимальным размером

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как создать архив `tst.zip`, разбив его на тома с максимальным размером `size`

```
import os, zipfile

def zip_dir(path, zp):
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        zp.write(entry.path)
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
            zip_dir(entry.path, zp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size = 1024
    with zipfile.ZipFile('tst.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
        zip_dir('libs', zip)
        zip_dir('.idea', zip)
```

Comment: вопрос не ясен. Не используйте нерабочий код в качестве спецификации задачи. Словами опишите, что вы хотите получить, приведите явный пример (что на входе, что на выходе). Укажите чем результаты приведённого кода отличаются от желаемых.

Comment: вопрос в том как разбить архив(tst.zip) на тома(по 7mb). ответ - никак

Comment: может есть библиокеки какие, но проще через subprocess

Comment: под словом "том" вы подразумеваете, разбиение `tst.zip` на `tst.zXX` файлы, как это WinZip делает? ([Split ZIP files](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)). Если совместимость с WinZip не нужна, то легко разбить файл на части, а потом их собрать (аналог `cat src/archive.z* > dest/archive.zip` в Питоне). Если нужна совместимость, то Гугл подсказывает `rarfile` модуль (не пользовался). Думаю (не проверял) 7zip утилита должна поддерживать разбиение архива не несколько файлов.